# macOS: zsh: command not found: mysqldump

Tags: mysql, macos, macos-catalina, mysqldumpslow

*I hope, it's the right forum for this question. But since there exist a `mysqldump` tag I think so.*

I'm using a Mac with macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H524).

Since I reinstalled Homebrew and therefore also deleted some folders, `mysqldump` isn't working any more. I always get the following error message:

```
zsh: command not found: mysqldump
```

Is it possible that I removed `mysqldump` by mistake? How can I make it working?

Comment: No, this question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. DBA or superuser sister sites of SO deal with such question on tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

First I detected the path of `mysqldump` with the following command:

```
locate mysqldump
```

This gave me: `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump`

Now, I can simply call `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump` instead of just  `mysqldump` in `Terminal`.